# Callback function with arguments using jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to call a javascript function with arguments on the click of a button in a dialog. Here is the flow of a simplified version that I can post here:
1) On click of an HTML button, pass a function and the button ID as arguments to a 'confirm' dialog.
2) On click of a 'Yes' in the confirmation dialog, call the passed in function that would just update the ID and value of the HTML button.

For some reason, the dialog keeps using the original argument and never gets the updated one. I think the code would do a better job of explaining the issue. Here is the HTML snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.js"></script>
<div id="confirmDialog"></div>
<div id="div_input">
    <input type="button" id="1" value="1" onClick="javascript:confirmAction(updateButton, this.id)" />
</div>
```

And here is the javascript snippet:

```
function confirmAction(onSuccessFunction, functionArg)
{
    var message = "Are you sure?";
    $('#confirmDialog').html(message);
    $('#confirmDialog').dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Confirm',
        width: 400,
        height: 150,
        buttons: {
            'Yes': function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                onSuccessFunction(functionArg);
            },
            'No': function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
    $("#confirmDialog").dialog('open');
};

function updateButton(buttonId)
{
    alert(buttonId);
    var buttonHTML = '';
    if(buttonId == '1')
    {
        buttonHTML = "<input type='button' id='2' value='2' onClick='javascript:confirmAction(updateButton, this.id)' />";
    }
    else
    {
        buttonHTML = "<input type='button' id='1' value='1' onClick='javascript:confirmAction(updateButton, this.id)' />";
    }

    document.getElementById("div_input").innerHTML = buttonHTML;
};
```

confirmAction(...) always calls updateButton(...) with buttonId as '1'. It works fine if I call updateButton(...) directly 'onClick'. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I strongly recommend using `document.getElementByid('..').setAttribute('id', ...);` instead of `.innerHTML`. (Deleted my earlier comment because I hadn't fully read OP)

Comment: taz, thanks for the tip. I changed the code, but that did not solve this issue. I would keep the modified code regardless since that is a better way of doing it.

Comment: I think that either the browser or jQuery is caching the value of the argument at some point. You shouldn't have to reset the callback assigned to the button - once you've changed the value of the `id` attribute, `this.id` should reflect this change. Your code looks OK to me unless I'm missing something also. Try it without `javascript:` in the text, and use something like Chrome's inspector to debug the script step by step and see what the value of `id` actually is when the function is called, and where the value it's using is coming from.

Comment: Removing `javascript:` did not help. Debugging in Chrome or Firebug shows me the correct value of `functionArg` when function `confirmAction(onSuccessFunction, functionArg)` is called, but as soon as the click event on 'Yes' is invoked, the value of `functionArg` in that scope changes to '1'. It does look like it is cached, but I am not sure where. Is there a way to "destroy" the dialog and create it every time?

Answer (score 2):

I posted this on jQuery forums too - https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-dialog-callback-function-with-arguments. As it turns out, this was a bug in older versions of jQuery and has now been fixed.